# Refreshing Javascript Timer

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval

I'm trying to making an correct/wrong application using javascript. This is my timer code:

```
var timeleft = 3;
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function() {
    timeleft--;
    document.getElementById("geri_sayim").textContent = timeleft;
    if (timeleft <= 0) {
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
        alert("time is up");
    }
},1000);
```

I have these functions:

```
CreateQuestion();
CheckAnswer();
isConfirm();
```

When I add this timer into `CreateQuestion()`, it works. But I want to stop this timer when the user clicks an answer button. For this reason I add this code into `CheckAnswer()`

```
clearInterval(downloadTimer);
```

But when I do this, the application doesn't work, and neither does the timer. Basically I want to countdown from 3 for each question. What's my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works for what you want to achieve:

#### HTML

```
<body onload="createQuestion();">
<p id="my-question"></p>
<p id="time-left">3</p>
<button onclick="checkAnswer();">Check Answer</button>
```

#### JavaScript

```
var timeleft = 3;
var myTimer;

function createQuestion() {
    // You create your question..
    document.getElementById("my-question").innerHTML = "Do you know the answer to this question?";
    // ..and start the timer..
    myTimer = setInterval(function() {
    timeleft--;
    document.getElementById("time-left").textContent = timeleft;
    if (timeleft <= 0) {
        clearInterval(myTimer);
        alert("Time is up!");
    }
    },1000);
}
function checkAnswer() {
    // Pause the time!
    clearInterval(myTimer);
    alert("Time paused!");
}
function isConfirm() {
    // Whatever other code you wrote for this function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
I edit `var downloadTimer` as `downloadTimer`